# Add element to array after sorting

Tags: php, arrays, asort

How to add element to begining array after [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) With keeping keys?

```
$array = array(
    564 => "plum",
    123 => "apple",
    543 => "lemon",
    321 => "cherry",
    );
    asort($array);
    $array[0]="all";
    print_r($array);
```

I get, index of key [0] is not at the beginig

```
Array(
[123] => apple
[321] => cherry
[543] => lemon
[564] => plum
[0] => all )
```

Need

```
Array(
[0] => all    
[123] => apple
[321] => cherry
[543] => lemon
[564] => plum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    564 => "plum",
    123 => "apple",
    543 => "lemon",
    321 => "cherry",
);
$array[0]="all";
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a === 'all') return -1;
  return strcmp($a, $b);
});
print_r($array);
```

Comment: it puts at the beginig, but i need keep my keys, not this Array
(
    [0] => all
    [1] => apple
    [2] => cherry
    [3] => lemon
    [4] => plumb
)

Comment: One more question, how to make 'all' global?

Comment: @polianych What do you mean by make `all` global, global variable?

Comment: $all = "all";
$array[0]=$all;
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
  if ($a === $all) return -1;
  return strcmp($a, $b);
});

Comment: @polianych CONST is better than global, `define('ALL', 'all');`

Answer (score 3):

After sorting your array, use [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) to prepend elements to the beginning of the array.

`array_unshift($arr, 'all')`

**Update:**

Note that `array_unshift()` will modify all numerical keys. To preserve the keys, use the `+` operator.

```
asort($array);
$array = array('all') + $array;
print_r($array);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => all
    [123] => apple
    [321] => cherry
    [543] => lemon
    [564] => plum
)
*/
```

Comment: He wants key information be remained, array_unshift will make you lost key information.

Answer (score 0):

Call `asort()` **after** adding values to the array. If you can guarantee the items that need to be added are already in reverse order and always come before the items already in the array, then you can use `$array = array($newitem) + $array`.

```
$array = array(
    564 => "plum",
    123 => "apple",
    543 => "lemon",
    321 => "cherry",
);
$array[0]="all";
asort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => all
    [123] => apple
    [321] => cherry
    [543] => lemon
    [564] => plum
)
```

This will also work when adding items that do *not* come before `apple`.

Comment: How to keep array keys asfter array_unshift()